# Ansible check if dictionary exists

Tags: dictionary, conditional-statements, ansible

i want to deploy additional `mysql` users - if set.
So i am using a dictionary. E.g.:

```
mysql_additional_users:
  user1:
    password: mysecretpass
    privs: "database1.*:ALL"
```

which works fine, as long as the dict is defined.
If not - it fails.

Although i tried to determine, if the dict is defined:

```
  - name: create additional mysql users
    mysql_user: name={{ item.key }} password={{ item.value.password }} priv={{ item.value.privs }} state=present      
    with_dict: "{{ mysql_additional_users }}"
    when: mysql_additional_users is defined
```

But i always get an error:

```
fatal: [<hostname>]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "ERROR! 'mysql_additional_users' is undefined"}
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`with_dict` is evaluated always. If you want to use it with `when`, try this:

```
with_dict: mysql_additional_users | default({})
when: mysql_additional_users is defined
```

it will evaluate to empty dict but the task will be skipped by `when`.