# How to set environment in ansible task only when variable is defined

Tags: ansible

I have two kinds of machines. One kind does not have internet access (say, we call them `outgoing restricted`), thus need a proxy to run command like `dnf install`, another kind can run `dnf install` directly.

I would like ansible to automatically use a proxy on those `outgoing restricted` hosts when running `dnf install`, thus I have the host file and the playbook below:

```yaml
outgoing_restricted:
  hosts:
    bar1.foo.com:
    bar2.foo.com:
  vars:
    # Sets up ssh forwarding for remote to use local machine
    # Need to enable and start squid with http_port 3128
    ansible_ssh_extra_args: "-R 3129:localhost:3128"
    proxy_env:
      http_proxy: "http://127.0.0.1:3129"
      https_proxy: "http://127.0.0.1:3129"
```

```yaml
- name: install redhat-lsb-core
  dnf:
    name:
      - redhat-lsb-core
    state: present
  environment: "{{ proxy_env }}"
```

However, the playbook fails when running on non-`outgoing restricted` hosts because on those hosts `proxy_env` is not defined.
My question is whether there is a way to specify `environment` only when `proxy_env` is defined. Adding `when: proxy_env is defined` under environment seems not working.

Comment: The thing is that you are trying to evaluate a dict, not a variable, the variable would be proxy_env.http_proxy is defined or proxy_env.https_proxy is defined. Maybe this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36308807/ansible-check-if-dictionary-exists

Comment: Thanks @ikora. Will you expand the comment into an answer below so that I can accept it? It works when the `environment` line is changed into `environment: "{{ proxy_env | default({}) }}"`

Comment: You sure? you solved it i just pointed in the correct way ^^ you can get the credit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The op solved it, as request I will try to elaborate a little bit.
I just pointed to check this URL: [Check if dict is empty or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36308807/ansible-check-if-dictionary-exists)

```yaml
 - name: install redhat-lsb-core
   dnf:
     name:
       - redhat-lsb-core
     state: present
   environment: "{{ proxy_env | default ({}) }}"
   when: proxy_env is defined
```

With the way op proposed:
Environment uses proxy_env but if it is not defined default filter will set the proxy_env to nothing so it will be able to validate that is empty correctly. (Empty or not defined). With this way he don't need to check if the variables inside the dict are defined or not, you are setting the entire dict `default ({})`.

Note: the op solved it by itself with my link, so credit to him also ^^.

Comment: This gave me the right idea for a case where the proxy url is just a single string variable `proxy_url`: `environment: "{{ ({'https_proxy': proxy_url}) if proxy_url else ({})}}"`